# Example code for dynamic parsing techniques

Tags: parsing

I would like to learn how to write dynamic parsers to perform tasks such as code-completion, highlighting, etc.

I have read the dragon book and written some parsers, but I would like more experience with handling incorrect code, especially code as it is being written.

IDEs like Eclipse and NetBeans obviously include code for stuff like this, but where?

What other projects / books might be relevant?

LISP or functional examples are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.antlr.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Check out xtext. It uses an ANTLR parser behind the scenes, but generates a syntax-highlighting editor, content assist, outlining, and many other features for you.

See http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/